# get the raw kinect data

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In openni, I think sensor_msgs encode data.

Because, rostopic echo /camera/depth/image and /camera/depth/disparity pulish not 16bit or 11bit, just 0~255.

I think the data is not actual depth data( distance )

I want to know depth value. But I don't know how to get the depth value.

I know the relation ( Z=fT/d ).

I think the fomula substituted raw data is right.

How can I get the raw kinect sensor data?

Or How can I get the actual depth value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42472/get-the-raw-kinect-data/) by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2979/ha/) on 2012-08-29**:
I think sensor_msgs/image message format is 8bit and using cv_bridge is 16bit or 32bit. Dose from 8bit to 32bit make loss accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [openni_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) documentation on the ROS wiki, you can see that the `openni_node` broadcasts several topics.

I think for the data that you are looking for, the topics of interest will be the `depth/image_raw` messages, or the `depth_registered/image_raw` if you have the OpenNI registration turned on.

The */image_raw messages are in the [sensor_msgs/Image](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) message format, which stores the data in a byte array, that can then be reassembled in the subscriber.  This is accomplished using [cv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge).

`cv_bridge` allows you to write code like this for your callback:

```
void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
  try
  {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::TYPE_32FC1);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
  }
  cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
  image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
}
```

`cv_ptr->image` will contain an OpenCV `cv::Mat`, in this case containing floating point values, which represent the depth in millimeters for that pixel.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shinnqy](https://answers.ros.org/users/15566/shinnqy/) on 2014-05-21**:
Can you tell how to access the floating point values in cv_ptr->image?